# Can't extract the numbers from the last bracket of each line using regex

Tags: python, regex, python-3.x, python-re

I'm trying to fetch the numbers within the last bracket of each line in a block of text. However, my current approach only fetch me the numbers of the last bracket.

I've tried with (the numbers may be of any digit):

```
import re

items = """
PTT KBALTHNAL (07) PETROL STATION (500003985)
ZHONGGUO (035) SHAXIAN 01 (5001039)
AHARATHAN BAIJIAING (0837) SU YOUMING (500086)
"""
ids = re.findall(r"\((\d+)\)$",items)
print(ids)
```

Output I get:

```
['500086']
```

Output I'm after:

```
['500003985','5001039','500086']
```

How can I extract the numbers from the last bracket of each line?

Comment: `re.findall(r"\((\d+)\)$",items, re.M)`. Or do not use `re.M` and use `(?:$|\n)`

Comment: `re.findall(r"\((\d+)\)\n",items)`

Comment: No need to accept wrong answers, it only does harm to SO.

Answer (score 1):

Lets do this by including only the last brackets of the string :

```
items = 'PTT KBALTHNAL (07) PETROL STATION (500003985)\nZHONGGUO (035) SHAXIAN 01 (5001039)\nAHARATHAN BAIJIAING (0837) SU YOUMING (500086)'
```

Here `(?!.)` excludes every occurences just after newline:

```
re.findall('\((\d+)\)(?!.)',items)
```

Here, we find digits with brackets,ending by new-line.
this gives you:

```
['500003985', '5001039', '500086']
```

Comment: `r"\((\d+)\)\n"` is wrong because you will never get a match on the last line. Do not repost others' wrong solutions if you do not understand them.

Comment: it gave the solution. i tested that

Comment: So, you did not even test it properly. You get [2 values](https://ideone.com/belZSo), not 3.

Comment: I got 3 values.

Comment: Yes, because you did not test if it matches at the end of the string.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew i edited the answer. now is it ok?

Comment: Now it is just  a wrong solution not answering the current question because `r"\((\d+)\)"` matches at any position inside the string, and there is no guarantee the valid matches are even ones.